# Create a program that calculates cost of a pizza, using OOP (JS) approach. I am very new to OOP , and I have this task to do after two hours lecture

Tags: javascript, oop

> I need some hints what to do next, because I'm stuck for two days.

> I DO NOT NEED TO DO THE WHOLE APP FOR ME...

You can create pizza of different sizes and different types:

> 1. Sizes:
>
>    - S (+50 UAH)
>    - M (+75 UAH)
>    - L (+100 UAH)
> 2. Types:
>
>    - VEGGIE (+50 UAH)
>    - MARGHERITA (+60 UAH)
>    - PEPPERONI (+70 UAH)
> 3. Extra ingredients:
>
>    - CHEESE (+7 UAH)
>    - TOMATOES (+5 UAH)
>    - MEAT (+9 UAH)
>
> Write a program that calculates the cost of a pizza and info about
> your pizza. Use an OOP approach (hint: you need a Pizza class,
> constants, methods for choosing options and calculating the required
> values).
>
> The code must be error-proof. Imagine another programmer using your
> class. If it passes the wrong type of pizza, for example, or the wrong
> kind of ingredient, an exception should be thrown (the error should
> not be silently ignored) (hint: you need PizzaException class).
>
> ## Pizza Class Description
>
> ## Class members:
>
> - **properties** (size and type are required):
>
>   1. size: size of pizza (must be from the allowedSizes property)
>   2. type: type of pizza (must be from the allowedTypes property)
> - **methods:**
>
>   - *addExtraIngredient(ingredient)*: add extra ingredient. Method must:
>
>     1. Accept only one parameter, otherwise show an error
>     2. Check if such an ingredient exists in allowedIngredients, if does not exist, show an error
>     3. Check if such an ingredient already exists; if there is, show error (you can add one ingredient only once)
>   - *removeExtraIngredient(ingredient)*: remove extra ingredient. Method must:
>
>     1. Accept only one parameter, otherwise show an error
>     2. Check if such an ingredient exists in allowedIngredients, if does not exist, show an error
>     3. Check if such an ingredient has already been added, if it not added, show an error, otherwise remove ingredient
>   - *getSize()*: returns size of pizza
>   - *getPrice()*: returns total price
>   - *getPizzaInfo()*: returns size, type, extra ingredients and price of pizza
>
> ## PizzaExeption Class Description
>
> Provides information about an error while working with a Pizza.
> Details are stored in the log property.
>
> **Class members:**
>
> - properties:
>
>   1. log: information about an error while working with a Pizza.
>
> I have this code so far:

```
'use strict';

function Pizza(size, type) {
this.size = size;
this.type = type;

/* Sizes, types and extra ingredients */
Pizza.SIZE_S = 50;
Pizza.SIZE_M = 75;
Pizza.SIZE_L = 100;

Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE = 50;
Pizza.TYPE_MARGHERITA = 60;
Pizza.TYPE_PEPPERONI = 70;

Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES = 5;
Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE = 7;
Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT = 9;

/* Allowed properties */
Pizza.allowedSizes = [SIZE_S, SIZE_M, SIZE_L];
Pizza.allowedTypes = [TYPE_VEGGIE, TYPE_MARGHERITA, TYPE_PEPPERONI];
Pizza.allowedExtraIngredients = [EXTRA_TOMATOES, EXTRA_CHEESE, EXTRA_MEAT];
}

function PizzaException() {}

let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE);
pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT);
console.log(`Price: ${pizza.getPrice()} UAH`); 

pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE);
pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES);
console.log(`Price with extra ingredients: ${pizza.getPrice()} UAH`); // Price: 121 UAH
console.log(`Is pizza large: ${pizza.getSize() === Pizza.SIZE_L}`); // Is pizza large: false

pizza.removeExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE);
console.log(`Extra ingredients: ${pizza.getExtraIngredients().length}`); // Extra ingredients: 2
console.log(pizza.getPizzaInfo()); //=> Size: SMALL, type: VEGGIE; extra ingredients: MEAT,TOMATOES; price: 114UAH.

// examples of errors
let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S); // Required two arguments, given: 1

let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.SIZE_S); // Invalid type

let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE);
pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT);
pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT); // Duplicate ingredient

let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE);
pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT); // Invalid ingredient
```

I managed to write this code, but I don't understand how to add extra ingredient to the total sum.

```
'use strict';

function Pizza(size, type) {
  let totalPrice = 0;
  this.size = size;
  this.type = type;
  
  this.getPrice = function () {
    // this.totalPrice = size.price + type.price + totalPrice ;
    return size.price + type.price + totalPrice;
  }
  
  this.addExtraIngredient = function (ingredient) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice + ingredient.price;
    return this.totalPrice;
  }
  
 }

/* Sizes, types and extra ingredients */
Pizza.SIZE_S = {size: 'small', price: 50};
Pizza.SIZE_M = {size: 'medium', price: 75};
Pizza.SIZE_L = {size: 'large', price: 100};

Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE = {type: 'veggy', price: 50};
Pizza.TYPE_MARGHERITA = {type: 'margherita', price: 60};
Pizza.TYPE_PEPPERONI = {type: 'pepperoni', price: 70};

Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES = {extra: 'tomatoes', price: 5};
Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE = {extra: 'cheese', price: 7};
Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT = {extra: 'meat', price: 9};


Pizza.allowedExtraIngredients = [Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES, Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE, Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT ];

let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE);
// add extra meat
pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT);

// check price
console.log(`Price: ${pizza.getPrice()} UAH`); //=> Price: 109 UAH
```

Comment: Please don't just post homework and expect others to solve it for you. You do have some code, but where are you stuck? Do you get an error? Is something not working? Is there something about OOP you don't understand?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I don't know a lot about OOP, and the code above is what I've managed to do so far. I am still trying to code, and if somebody just give me a hint what to do next, it'll be much appreciated.
P.S. I don't expect of somebody to do the whole work for me.

Comment: The problem is that you don't ask questions or for help regarding specific issues that you are having. You posted your homework, your code and seem to be expecting people to jump in and solve it or give you tips.

Comment: Diogo, I have specific issues what to do next, as I'd mentioned before I don't know a lot about OOP. I can code this application by functions. I need hints what to do next.
P.S. And if I would be a good programmer, and stumbled upon this question, I would give some hints without any comments as for "expecting people jump and solve it", "expect others to solve it for you", etc.
Guys I wish you good luck and to read and follow advices from the book of Dale Carnegie "How To Win Friends and Influence People"

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: I'll gladly help you. But if you don't know "what to do next", it means you are stuck on something. Maybe you have doubts implementing a certain behavior or you are getting a specific error. That's what I'm looking for. Otherwise, I don't know how to help you as well.

Comment: I am stuck on the further steps: how to structure the code, where to put methods getSize(), getPrice(), getPizzaInfo(). How to implement one of these methods, so I can see it and create the other two myself, using yours as an example.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I understand the intent, but the solution isn't about pizzas at all but orders and extras.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. We're not here to do your homework. Understand the problem, then ask the part where you're having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to do this task. Thanks a lot for Kokodoko advice. Below is the answer:

```
'use strict';
function Pizza(size, type) {
  const requiredArguments = 2;
  if (arguments.length !== requiredArguments) {
    throw new PizzaException(`Required two arguments, given: ${arguments.length}`)
  }

  if (!Pizza.allowedTypes.includes(type) || !Pizza.allowedSizes.includes(size)) {
    throw new PizzaException('Invalid type');
  }

  const negativeIndex = -1;
  let _size = size;
  let extrasType = [];
  let extrasPrice = [];
  this.type = type;

  Pizza.prototype.getSize = function () {
    return _size.size;
  };

  Pizza.prototype.getPrice = function () {
    return _size.price + this.type.price;
  };

  Pizza.prototype.addExtraIngredient = function (ingredient) {
    if (!ingredient) {
      throw new PizzaException('Invalid ingredient')
    }

    if (type.type === 'VEGGIE' && ingredient.extra === 'MEAT') {
      throw new PizzaException('Invalid ingredient');
    }
    
    if (extrasType.includes(ingredient.extra)) {
      throw new PizzaException('Duplicate ingredient');
    }
    
    extrasPrice.push(_size.price += ingredient.price);
    extrasType.push(ingredient.extra);
    return _size.price;
  };

  Pizza.prototype.removeExtraIngredient = function (ingredient) {
    extrasPrice.pop(this.type.price -= ingredient.price);
    const index = extrasType.indexOf(ingredient.extra);
    if (index > negativeIndex) {
      extrasType.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return this.type.price;
  };

  Pizza.prototype.getExtraIngredients = function () {
    return extrasPrice;
  };

  Pizza.prototype.getPizzaInfo = function () {
    return `Size: ${_size.size}, type: ${
      type.type
    }; extra ingredients: ${extrasType}; price: ${
      _size.price + this.type.price
    }UAH`;
  };
}

/* Sizes, types and extra ingredients */
Pizza.SIZE_S = { size: 'SMALL', price: 50 };
Pizza.SIZE_M = { size: 'MEDIUM', price: 75 };
Pizza.SIZE_L = { size: 'LARGE', price: 100 };

Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE = { type: 'VEGGIE', price: 50 };
Pizza.TYPE_MARGHERITA = { type: 'MARGHERITA', price: 60 };
Pizza.TYPE_PEPPERONI = { type: 'PEPPERONI', price: 70 };

Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES = { extra: 'TOMATOES', price: 5 };
Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE = { extra: 'CHEESE', price: 7 };
Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT = { extra: 'MEAT', price: 9 };

/* Allowed properties */
Pizza.allowedSizes = [Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.SIZE_M, Pizza.SIZE_L];
Pizza.allowedTypes = [Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE, Pizza.TYPE_MARGHERITA, Pizza.TYPE_PEPPERONI];
Pizza.allowedExtraIngredients = [Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES, Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE, Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT];

function PizzaException(log) {
  this.log = log;
  PizzaException.prototype.log = function () {
    return log;
  };
}

//////////////// Tests //////////////////
// // small pizza, type Margherita  110 UAH
// let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_MARGHERITA);
// // add extra meat 110 + 9 = 119 
// pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT);
// console.log(`Price: ${pizza.getPrice()} UAH`); //Price: 119 UAH
// // add extra cheese 119 + 7 = 126
// pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE);
// // add extra tomatoes 126 + 5 = 131;
// pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES);
// console.log(`Price with extra ingredients: ${pizza.getPrice()} UAH`); // Price: 131 UAH
// // check pizza size
// console.log(`Is pizza large: ${pizza.getSize() === Pizza.SIZE_L}`); //Is pizza large: false
// // remove extra ingredient cheese 131 - 7 = 124
// pizza.removeExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE); 
// console.log(`Extra ingredients: ${pizza.getExtraIngredients().length}`); // Extra ingredients: 2
// console.log(pizza.getPizzaInfo()); //Size: SMALL, type: MARGHERITA; extra ingredients: MEAT,TOMATOES; price: 124UAH.

//////////// Examples of errors ///////////////////////
/////////////////////////// 1 ///////////////////////
// let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S); // "Required two arguments, given: 1"

/////////////////////////// 2 ///////////////////////
// let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.SIZE_S); // "Invalid type"

/////////////////////////// 3 ///////////////////////
// let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_PEPPERONI);
// pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT);
// pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT); // "Duplicate ingredient"

/////////////////////////// 4 ///////////////////////
// let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE);
// pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT); // "Invalid ingredient"

/////////////////////////// 5 ///////////////////////
// let pizza = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE);
// pizza.addExtraIngredient(Pizza.EXTRA_CORN); // "Invalid ingredient"
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to check if such an ingredient exists in allowedIngredients inside addExtraIngredient.

```
Pizza.prototype.addExtraIngredient = function (ingredient) {
     ...
     if (!Pizza.allowedExtraIngredients.includes(ingredient)) {
        throw new PizzaException('Invalid ingredient');
      }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to implement methods, I could suggest the following. By the way, I use the `class` keyword here instead of `function` to declare a class. I think it more clearly describes the intent of your code (which is creating a class, not a function).

```
class Pizza {

    static SIZE_S = 50
    static TYPE_VEGGIE = "veggie"

    constructor(size, type) {
        this.size = size
        this.type = type
    }
    getSize() {
        return this.size
    }
    getPizzaInfo() {
        return `Here is your ${this.type} pizza of size ${this.size}!`
    }
}

let p = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE)
console.log(p.getPizzaInfo())
```

UPDATE

The above code converted to ES5 using `prototype` to add methods:

```
function Pizza(size,type) {
  this.size = size
  this.type = type
}

Pizza.prototype.getSize = function() {
      return this.size
}
Pizza.prototype.getPizzaInfo = function() {
      return `Hey, here is your ${this.type} pizza of ${this.size} size!`
}

Pizza.SIZE_S = 50
Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE = 50

let p = new Pizza(Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE)
console.log(p.getPizzaInfo())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. Unfortunately I was given a clear instruction (restriction) to use constructor function (old-school style ). That's why it is mind blowing for me. I know a bit more about class (ES6).

Comment: You can always convert ES6 down to old-school javascript using this live babel tool : https://babeljs.io/repl#. In short, you have to add your method to `Pizza.prototype = function() {...}`. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your task, but done with ES6 classes approach

```
class Pizza {

    constructor(type, size) {
        this.extraIngredient = []
        if (arguments.length < 2) {
            return new PizzaException(`Required two arguments, given: ${arguments.length}`)
        }
        if (!Pizza.allowedTypes.includes(type) || !Pizza.allowedSizes.includes(size)) {
            return new PizzaException('Invalid type')
        }
        this.type = type.type
        this.size = size.size
        this.price = type.price + size.price
    }

    addExtraIngredient(ingredient) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            return new PizzaException('You can add only one ingredient per time')
        }
        if (!Pizza.allowedExtraIngredients.includes(ingredient)) {
            return new PizzaException('You cannot add that ingredient')
        }
        if (this.extraIngredient.includes(ingredient)) {
            return new PizzaException('You can add one ingredient only once')
        } else {
            this.extraIngredient.push(ingredient)
        }
    }

    removeExtraIngredient(ingredient) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            return new PizzaException('You can remove only one ingredient per time')
        }
        if (!Pizza.allowedExtraIngredients.includes(ingredient)) {
            return new PizzaException('You cannot remove that ingredient')
        }
        if (this.extraIngredient.includes(ingredient)) {
            this.extraIngredient.splice(this.extraIngredient[ingredient], 1)
        } else {
            return new PizzaException('You cannot remove the ingredient that was not added')
        }
    }

    getSize() {
        return `Pizza size: ${this.size}`
    }

    getPrice() {
        return this.extraIngredient.length
            ? this.extraIngredient.reduce((a, b) => a + b.price, 0) + this.price + 'UAH'
            : this.price + 'UAH'
    }

    getPizzaInfo() {
        return `${this.getSize()}, type: ${this.type}; extra ingredients: ${this.extraIngredient
            .map(item => item.ingredient).join(',') || 'none'}; price: ${this.getPrice()}`
    }
}

Pizza.SIZE_S = {size: 'small', price: 50}
Pizza.SIZE_M = {size: 'medium', price: 75}
Pizza.SIZE_L = {size: 'large', price: 100}

Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE = {type: 'veggie', price: 50}
Pizza.TYPE_MARGHERITA = {type: 'margherita', price: 60}
Pizza.TYPE_PEPPERONI = {type: 'pepperoni', price: 70}

Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES = {ingredient: 'tomatoes', price: 5}
Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE = {ingredient: 'cheese', price: 7}
Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT = {ingredient: 'meat', price: 9}

Pizza.allowedSizes = [Pizza.SIZE_S, Pizza.SIZE_M, Pizza.SIZE_L]
Pizza.allowedTypes = [Pizza.TYPE_VEGGIE, Pizza.TYPE_MARGHERITA, Pizza.TYPE_PEPPERONI]
Pizza.allowedExtraIngredients = [Pizza.EXTRA_TOMATOES, Pizza.EXTRA_CHEESE, Pizza.EXTRA_MEAT]

class PizzaException {
    constructor(log) {
        throw new Error(log)
    }
}
```